# Wordpress Site and W3 Total Cache through Apache PHP-FPM FastCGI

Tags: php, wordpress, apache2.2, w3-total-cache, mod-fastcgi

I've setup an Apache server with Wordpress and after installing several plugins I noticed the page load times went up to 30 seconds or more so I followed several guides to fine-tune and Speed up Apache by removing modules, enabling deflate, changing worker processes, etc...

One of the changes I made was removing mod-php and using php-fpm through mod-fastcgi, afterwards I noticed several bizarre errors. W3 Total Cache reported that htaccess was not writeable despite the fact it belongs to the same user and group and I even made it world-writable (777 Permissions) and minify can't work because it can't write any changes to htaccess.

Not only that but Minify is giving off 2 more bizarre messages

```
Minify Auto encountered an error. The filename length value is most likely too high for your host. It is currently 150. The plugin is trying to solve the issue for you
```

To which it sits there trying to fix and then says

```
Minify Auto does not work properly. Try using Minify Manual instead or try another Minify cache method. You can also try a lower filename length value manually on settings page by checking "Disable the Minify Auto automatic filename test”
```

Also the compatibility check produces strange messages as well claiming that a number of modules aren't detected which are loaded, I did some quick research and found that the modules are just simply difficult to detect through fast-gi but I wonder if the plugin is doing anything given it cant detect them.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

## W3 Total Cache 'Minify Auto' under Apache/PHP-FPM

I experienced the same issue with W3 Total Cache (W3TC) and its 'Minify Auto' feature under Apache with PHP-FPM.

### Problem in brief

When PHP is invoked in FastCGI mode, some CGI variables such as `SCRIPT_NAME` and `PATH_INFO` are not always set to the values expected by script developers. In my case, the value of `SCRIPT_NAME` was the path of the `php5-fcgi` executable (`/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi`), rather than that of the PHP script itself.

The minify module code in the W3TC plugin expects `SCRIPT_NAME` to be set correctly, and fails when it isn't.

### Solution

The php.ini directive, `cgi.fix_pathinfo`, works around this 'CGI variables' issue when enabled. In my case, I had disabled this setting, and reenabling it resulted in generation of the correct `SCRIPT_NAME` and resolved the minification issue.

#### Instructions for a Debian/Ubuntu system

To reenable, change the setting in `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini`:

```
cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
```

And reload the php-fpm service:

```
sudo service php-fpm reload
```

#### Caveat

Note there have been security concerns dating from 2010 regarding the use of the `cgi.fix_pathinfo` setting in misconfigured Nginx sites (see [here](http://cnedelcu.blogspot.com.au/2010/05/nginx-php-via-fastcgi-important.html) for details), however I haven't been able to reproduce this under an Apache setup.

Since PHP 5.3.9, a (poorly documented) new FPM configuration directive, [`security.limit_extensions`](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55181) has been introduced. This defaults to limiting execution to `.php` files only, and as far as I can tell this should mitigate the historical security issues.

### Problem in detail (for those who care)

The broken CGI variables cause a problem in the W3TC function that derives the cache directory path.

This in turn causes the minify `.htaccess` file to be written to disk with the malformed cache path in the `RewriteBase` directive.

In my case, it was:

```
RewriteBase inify/
```

Rather than:

```
RewriteBase /wp-content/cache/minify/
```

This affects the subsequent rewrite rules, which ultimately prevents the minification code (which relies on these rules) from being invoked correctly.